# How to do LAG like implementation in KSQLDB?

Tags: sql, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I've recently started working with ksql and wanted to check if someone can help me with a query design. The problem statement is that I have a video conferencing app where a broadcaster can start and pause the stream multiple times. I want to get the total played time and the total paused time for that stream. I have a click stream data which consists of start and pause timestamps. How should I go about it so that I can generate an optimized view.

Any help is very deeply appreciated :)

Thank You

Comment: Hi Abhimanyu, you'll generally get more time from community members if you provide more information, and especially show that you've spent some time researching this.

Answer (score 2):

### Grouping events

The first problem you'll need to solve is how are you going to group start/stop events together?

Likely, you'll want to group them by some kind of `USER_ID` or other attribute that uniquely identifies the broadcaster that's starting/stopping the stream.

Likely, you'll also want to group by the some kind of `STREAM_ID` or other attribute that uniquely identifies the stream being played.

This may be sufficient, it you only want the total play time per-broadcaster, per-video. However, you may also want to take *time* into account. For example, if I watch a video today, and then watch it again tomorrow, is that two viewing sessions, with two independent view time totals, or do you not care?

One way of grouping events in time is using session windows. Before you sessionize the data you'd need to define the parameters that define your session.  Here's a [good example of using session windows in ksqlDB](https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/create-session-windows/ksql.html).

Another way of grouping events in time is using tumbling windows. Here's a [good example of using tumbling windows](https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/create-tumbling-windows/ksql.html).

### Calculating play time

Once you've grouped your events, you'll likely need to calculate the play time. For example, if I start playing at time 5, and stop playing at time 8, then the amount of time I was watching the video is `5 - 8 = 3`.

This requires capturing the play event and waiting for the stop event, and then outputting the difference in time.  And doing some in a fault tolerant way.

At the time of writing, this would require a custom UDAF (custom user defined aggregate function).

A custom UDAF could capture the start event, store it for future reference, and output a '0' for the play time, and then when it sees the corresponding stop event it can remove the start event from its state, calculate the play time and return it.

Here's a [good example of writing a custom UDF in ksqlDB](https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/udf/ksql.html), though you require a custom UDAF, which are covered [here](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/create-a-user-defined-function/#aggregation-functions).

There is currently a [PR open with an enhancement to the LATEST_BY_OFFSET method](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/pull/6014) that may well serve your purpose. This enhances the method to allow it to capture the last N value, rather than just the last 1 value. Likely, this will be released in ksqlDB v0.13, and you can always pull the code and compile it locally, if you have any development experience. If it doesn't serve your purpose, then you may be able to use it as the starting point for developing your own.

Of course, these solutions requires your stream of source events to be correctly ordered, so that stop events never come *before* their associated play events.

### Aggregating

Once you've calculated the play time between a pair of start/stop events, you'll then need to aggregate them. Here's a [good example of how to aggregate in ksqlDB](https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/create-stateful-aggregation-sum/ksql.html).

Comment: Hi Andrew Thanks for the reply. I have been researching into ksql from the last two months and I don't have much background into development especially java , I come from a statistics background. Hence I wanted to reiterate where I've been stuck upon -:
Suppose a broadcaster starts a stream at 12 pm pauses at 12:05 then again restarts at 12:08 and ends at 12:10. Here the total playtime is 7 mins and 3 mins is the pause time.

Comment: To get this number I've been trying to create two tables namely pause and play capturing all the timestamps of such events using window tumbling of say 1 sec and later subtract them using a counter which exists in both. But I wanted to check is it scalable on a large scale where I expect around 20-30k live sessions daily.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Consider updating your question to contain the SQL you've been trying, sample input data and expected/required output.